# Electron global variable does not persist between route/URL changes on React page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm currently developing an Electron application that is wrapping a client's website (which is written in React).

I'm using a preload script, and I'm defining a global variable like so:

```
process.once('loaded', () => {
    global.foo = () => {
        console.log("foo");
    };
});
```

In the client code the following code is called from several locations:

```
import { doFoo } from 'foobar';
```

In foobar.js, I have the following code:

```
export function doFoo() {
    foo();
}
```

When I import and call doFoo from the landing page, everything works fine.
When React changes route/URL, I get **Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined**.

How do I make sure the global variable is *truly* global and persists between route changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It was because one of the imports was called from an iframe, so I had to do the following changes (in foobar.js) to make it work:

```
export function doFoo() {
    if (typeof foo != 'undefined') {
        foo();
    } else {
        parent.foo(); // called from an iframe.
    }
}
```